# Show <marquee> tag in a single row

Tags: php, html, dynamic, while-loop, marquee

[image: Illustration of what I want]
I have the following code but it shows marquee output in 2 rows, I want it  to appear in a single row.

Check screenshot..
Please help.

I know marquee is deprecated but I have to use it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

```
<?php 
   $sql = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT fromcity, tocity from tblbooking order by id DESC LIMIT 2");
   $sql->execute() ;
?>
<h3 style="color: #f52d31; text-align: center; background-color: #8080807a;"> Latest Rides </h3>
<marquee>
   <?php while( $row = $sql->fetch()) : ?>
   <div>
      <tr>
         <li style="font-size: 20px; color: red; list-style: none; background-color: #cac2c2b8; width: 20%;">
            <i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i> Origin : 
            <td><?php echo $row['fromcity']; ?></td>
         </li>
         <li style="font-size: 20px;color: red; list-style: none; background-color: #cac2c247; width: 20%;">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Destin : 
            <td><?php echo $row['tocity']; ?></td>
         </li>
      </tr>
   </div>
   <br>
   <?php endwhile ?>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Using a table would be the easiest way to get around that problem.

Comment: Yeah, tables has sometimes responsiveness  issue.. That's why I did it this way. 

For your information : marquee is deprecated but I had to use to achieve specific requirements. 
Thank You everyone. I solved the issue by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

Actually, float:left; did the magic and here is a screenshot after.
[image]